# If I want non-recursive deep copy of my object, should I override copy or deepcopy in Python?

Tags: python, deep-copy

An object of my class has a list as its attribute. That is,

```
class T(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.arr = [x, y]
```

When this object is copied, I want a separate list `arr`, but a shallow copy of the content of the list (e.g. `x` and `y`). Therefore I decide to implement my own copy method, which will recreate the list but not the items in it. But should I call this `__copy__()` or `__deepcopy__()`? Which one is the right name for what I do, according to Python semantics?

My guess is `__copy__()`. If I call `deepcopy()`, I would expect the clone to be totally decoupled from the original. However, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) says:

> A *deep copy* constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
>   inserts *copies* into it of the objects found in the original.

It is confusing by saying "inserts *copies* into it" instead of "inserts *deep copies* into it", especially with the emphasis.

Comment: the concept of "deep" comes from the recursive part, otherwise saying "A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then inserts deep copies into it" would be a recursive description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct magic method for you to implement here is `__copy__`.

The behaviour you've described is deeper than what the default behaviour of copy would do (i.e. for an object which hasn't bothered to implement `__copy__`), but it is not deep enough to be called a deepcopy.  Therefore you should implement `__copy__` to get the desired behaviour.

Do not  make the mistake of thinking that simply assigning another name makes a "copy":

```
t1 = T('google.com', 123)
t2 = t1  # this does *not* use __copy__
```

That just binds another name to the same instance.  Rather, the `__copy__` method is hooked into by a function:

```
import copy
t2 = copy.copy(t1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought the same but felt doubtful when I read the Python documentation. Why don't Python make `copy` a builtin like `str` and `repr`?

Comment: Because there are not many use-cases for it.  Python devs generally work in a style which avoids side-effects so they don't really care about where in memory an object lives.

Comment: @user31039 Because most builtins can be easily copied. For example an instance can be passed to the constructor (`dict({'a': 1})` makes a copy) or have an explicit `copy` method: `{1,2,3}.copy()` or have even a slicing syntax to make a copy: `[1,2,3][:]`. For normal python programs using the builtins you just don't need the copy module. Advertising: I touched some of these points in my answer as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

It actually depends on the desired behaviour of your class that factor into the decision what to override (`__copy__` or `__deepcopy__`).

In general `copy.deepcopy` works mostly correctly, it just copies everything (recursivly) so you only need to override it if there is some attribute that **must not** be copied (ever!).

On the other hand one should define `__copy__` only if users (including yourself) wouldn't expect changes to propagate to copied instances. For example if you simply wrap a mutable type (like `list`) or use mutable types as implementation detail.

Then there is also the case that the minimal set of attributes to copy isn't clearly defined. In that case I would also override `__copy__` but maybe raise a `TypeError` in there and possible include one (or several) dedicated public `copy` methods.

However in my opinion the `arr` counts as implementation detail and thus I would override `__copy__`:

```
class T(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.arr = [x, y]

    def __copy__(self):
        new = self.__class__(*self.arr)
        # ... maybe other stuff
        return new
```

Just to show it works as expected:

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy

x = T([2], [3])
y = copy(x)
x.arr is y.arr        # False
x.arr[0] is y.arr[0]  # True
x.arr[1] is y.arr[1]  # True

x = T([2], [3])
y = deepcopy(x)
x.arr is y.arr        # False
x.arr[0] is y.arr[0]  # False
x.arr[1] is y.arr[1]  # False
```

---

Just a quick note about expectations:

Users generally expect that you can pass an instance to the constructor to create a minimal copy (similar or identical to `__copy__`) as well. For example:

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4]
lst2 = list(lst1)
lst1 is lst2        # False
```

Some Python types have an explicit `copy` method, that (if present) should do the same as `__copy__`. That would allow to explicitly pass in parameters (however I haven't seen this in action yet):

```
lst3 = lst1.copy()  # python 3.x only (probably)
lst3 is lst1        # False
```

If your class should be used by others you probably need to consider these points, however if you only want to make your class work with `copy.copy` then just overwrite `__copy__`.

Answer (score 1):

I think overwriting `__copy__` is a good idea, as explained by the other answers with great detail. An alternative solution might be to write an explicit copy method to be absolutely clear on what is called:

```
class T(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.arr = [x, y]

    def copy(self):
        return T(*self.arr)
```

When any future reader sees `t.copy()` he then immediately knows that a custom copy method has been implemented. The disadvantage is of course that it might not play well with third-party libraries that use `copy.copy(t)`.

Comment: so your answer to the question "should I override copy or deepcopy?"  from the title is.... neither and forget about `copy.copy` all together?

Comment: It's just an alternative idea. I think it has some advantages, but I am also completely aware of the negative implications.

Comment: ok except that if `__copy__` is defined it is called when you do `copy.copy(t)`.  It still seems to me you aren't really offering a solution to the question asked. (I assume downvoter was for that reason)

Comment: Fair enough – I will amend my answer. However, I think the other answers to this question go into great detail and give very good reasoning for overwriting `__copy__` already.